# Can CSS subclasses impact on page performance?

Tags: css

Let's consider the case if there are only subclasses which do nothing. As instance:

```
.item.01 { 
     font: bold;
}
.item.02 { 
     font: bold; 
}

...

and so on
```

The question is: what amount of such subclasses can

- impacts page load performace
- impacts page load performace hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no elements that have those classes then there will be no performance penalty for painting the css.

However, if there was a large amount of these, this would increase the css file size. This would impact the time it takes to download the css file and parse it.

So the answer really is, it will affect your performance regardless. You should be safe with a few hundred or so without any major issues, but if there is thousands, you will see performance penalties.

Maybe try purging your css if they are unused but need to generate them regardless.

https://purgecss.com/

Comment: Thx for the link!